# Combining rows in SQL query

Tags: sql, distinct, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I currently have a SQL query in snowflake where I am trying to just show the DISTINCT QUESTIONS.
When I run this one question, for instance Do you like ice cream?, shows up 5 times. I tried adding group by question and it still doesn't work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT QUESTION FROM X
GROUP BY QUESTION
```

Is there a way to either have just the one question show, or if they aren't truly unique, combine those five rows into one one based on the fact that they are similar?

Comment: The problem can only be that the questions are not really exactly the same, right?

Comment: show data so we can see if they can be grouped together

Comment: Is your query exactly the same with the above? I mean if you also select the primary key of the table not just the question, the row would be different from others.A query with distinct, some fields can be same, but you should look at the rows if they are same or not.

Answer (score 0):

see if doing this helps:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(QUESTION)
FROM X
```

Answer (score 0):

Number 1: You do not need to use GROUP BY and DISTINCT together in the query. In your query, both GROUP BY and DISTINCT doing the same for you. You can perform-

```
--Either
SELECT QUESTION 
FROM X
GROUP BY QUESTION

--OR
SELECT DISTINCT QUESTION 
FROM X
```

Number 2: Now your issue comes here. You are claiming same Question coming 5 times in your query output which is not possible with your written query. Somehow they are different comparing with each other.

> May be there are "Spaces" either at starting or ending. You can solve it by using TRIM as "Somdeb Mukherjee" suggested.
>
> Or you have CASE sensitivity in you Question value which basically depends on your database as some databases are case sensitive.
>
> Or some additional differences in the string that you are missing.